# React Native - how to rerender a component inside the another component without state

Tags: react-native

Here is a situation:

```
export default class T2 extends Component {
render(){
.
.
.
<Text>{this.state.v1}</Text>
.
.
.
.
}
```

}

now generally, I could just update/set the state for `v1` and this will rerender `Text` as it actually rerenders `T2` itself.

But why should the whole T2 rerender! There should be a way to just rerender `Text` tag, and not the whole T2.. There could be 100s of items above and below it and I dont think it would best to rerender everything

Is there a way to rerender components used inside the render of container component?

Thanks